# What is micro C in a circuit diagram?

Tags: sensors, ir, resistor

This is probably a simple question but I am a beginner with these things. What does the micro C part of the circuit diagram mean? The diagram is from the datasheet of the tssp77038 IR receiver. Does it want there to be a capacitor on the output?
(http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1915248.pdf?_ga=1.234529246.1943069395.1480959857)

[image]

Comment: If you Google "µC" you reach the page [Microcontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "Micro Controller" - you know it as "Arduino".